# python for split all line and save in new output file

Tags: python, split

i have already this code

```
#!usr.bin/env pyhton
asal = open("honeyd.txt")
tujuan = open("test.rule", "W")
satu = asal.readline()
a = satu.split();
b = 'alert ' + a[0]+' ' + a[1] + ' -> ' + a[2]+' '+ a[3]
c = str(b)
tujuan.write(c)
asal.close()
tujuan.close()
```

but this code is just read a line and split it.
Actually, i have 3 lines in my "honeyd.txt"
and my goal is to split all of the line.

how to split all of the lines and save it into "test.rule"?

Comment: Can you provide example input and desired output please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over the input lines; right now you only call `readline` once. Best done just by looping over the input file handle directly:

```
with open('honeyd.txt') as infile, open('test.rule', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write('alert {} {} -> {} {}'.format(*line.split())
```

Also note the use of `with` statement, which saves you from having to call `close` manually.